# Want to change logo and search box position in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I want chnage my logo and search box position from bydefault.

I want change logo and search box position with HOME tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your **default.xml** file in you custom theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="-" />
        <move element="logo" destination="store.menu"  before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can get output something like this.

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this may help you! :)

Comment: No. Its not working for me in default.xml. Can you give exact path of file?

Comment: After adding above code in your default.xml please run **php bin/magento cache:flush** once and then check.

Comment: You can not able to see that logo and search input box there. but if you'll check in inspect element you can see it with menu.

Comment: is above solution was helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Only Add some CSS to Change Width of Search Bar No Need to Overwrite any File.

Add This CSS code to your .css file

```
.page-wrapper .block.block-search {
    width: 100%;
}
```

For CSS File Path

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/Magento_Theme/web/css/cssFileName.css
```

OR

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/{themme_name}/web/css/cssFileName.css
```

***NOTE:- Magento has multiple Theme for Different Stores so Kindly Check which Theme are Currently used. to check follow this step.***

Reference Link:- [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)

**And You can Also Overwite files**

You have to just copy core file into your theme and customize as per your need,

```
app/vendor/magento/module_search/view/forntend/templates/form.mini.phtml



app/design/frontend/{vendor_name}/{themme_name}/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

Clear cache. Your changes are applied.

***I Hope This Helps You.***